# Use eval to update local variables?

Tags: python, eval

I want to provide `eval` some compiled code (via `compile`) that when evaluated should update some variables in the `locals` I passed in.

```
x = 5
global_dict = {'__builtins__': None}
local_dict = {'x': x}
code = compile("x = x * 2", "<string>", "single")

# This updates x
eval(code, global_dict, globals())

# This doesn't
eval(code, global_dict, local_dict)

# Nor does this...
eval(code, global_dict, globals().copy())
```

Comment: *`local_dict` is updated*... what exactly do you want?

Comment: Are you expecting `local_dict['x']` to be the `x` global variable you defined? [That's not how variables work in Python.](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: The `{'x': x}` doesn't create a reference to the local variable `x` defined at the beginning of your code snippet, so it's not doing what (I think) you want (and I don't think is possible).

Comment: I want `x` to be updated. I have a few variables that I want to pass in as the context for eval. The code is eval should be able to edit / change those variables, but ONLY those variables.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that works! Thanks. I didn't realize that locals was being updated. Could post a formal answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga as a point of clarification as well. What I actually want is NOT for the local variable `x` to be updated but rather `x` in the `local_dict`. How I'm using it is that I have a dictionary full of variables that I want the code to have access to update. So passing `locals` to eval and then saving `locals` works for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do it like this (it works in CPython 3.6.3 anyway), although it not OK to update the dictionary returned by `locals()` (see **Note** in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals).

```
x = 5
code = compile("x = x * 2", "<string>", "single")
eval(code, locals())
print('x:', x)  # -> x: 10
```

Note, too, as @juanpa.arrivillaga pointed out in a comment, that at the module-level, `locals()`is the same as `globals()`—so you can avoid the restriction by using it instead. In other words, `eval(code, globals())` would be better and avoids the issue.

(I verified that they're the same with an `assert locals() == globals()` at the beginning of the code to verify they're the same.)

Comment: probably good to point out that in the global scope, `locals() is globals()`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Since that's the case, do you know for sure it would make it OK to modify the returned dictionary (or should one just use `globals()` instead if this is being done at the module-level and not in a function?)

Comment: Well, what do you mean by "OK"? My impressions is that you can modify the `dict` returned by `locals` all you want, but it isn't guaranteed to affect anything **unless** it happens to be `globals()` in disguise.